# Access Menu Items in OS/X In single Keystroke like in Linux or Windows

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any way to do this in Mac? Using deadkeys on a custom keyboard layout, or a preference (I doubt that one .. but just in case..).

What takes one keystroke in Windows/Linux -> to access say "File" menu by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> - takes a minimum of 3 on Mac:

- Access the Menu Bar. This is typically an awkward shortcut
- Type 'f'
- Hit down arrow (to actually see the menu items..)

Then there is the question of the mnemonics. Are we supposed to use a mouse (much slower and takes hand off the keyboard) or down arrow keys (likewise..)

Is there a workaround to get those to work?

Answer (score -1):

OSX provides keyboard shortcuts usually with the *command* key.  Like other systems, some are predefined, as shown here:

- [Pwn your Mac with the best OS X keyboard shortcuts](http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/mac-os-x-keyboard-shortcuts/)
- [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)

You can define your own shortcuts, using the “Shortcuts” tab in the Keyboard preferences, discussed here:

- [How to Customize Your OS X Keyboard and Add Shortcuts](http://www.howtogeek.com/209725/how-to-customize-your-os-x-keyboard-and-add-shortcuts/?PageSpeed=noscript)

Comment: This does not answer the question. I am not interested in creating a slew of app specific shortcuts. Intellij alone has dozens and dozen of menu items: making up a bunch of Command-Blah does not at all replace Alt-<menu level 1 letter><menu level 2 option letter. can quickly see all of the menu items and type the first letter (or even first letters if need be). After doing it a couple of times it becomes automatic and can be done in milliseconds.